# trying to get values of tags in php

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

```
<span class="p_txt1 p_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="value 1">
<b>value 2</b>
</span>
<span class="p_txt1 p_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="value 1">
<b>value 2</b>
</span>
<span class="p_txt1 p_1">
<input type="checkbox" value="value 1">
<b>value 2</b>
</span>
```

i am trying to get value 1 from input and value 2 from bold tag but its not working

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadhtml($contents);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$dataString =  "";
$fruits = $xpath->query("//span[@class='p_txt1 p_1']");
foreach($fruits as $fruit) { 
echo $xmlDate = $fruit->getElementsByTagName( "b" ),"<br>";
}
```

can anybody help

Comment: I guess you need to echo the `nodeValue` property

Comment: it works but i want to get value 1 from input too with value 2

so it will be like 
value 1 - value 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadhtml($contents);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$dataString =  "";
$fruits = $xpath->query("//span[@class='p_txt1 p_1']");
foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
   foreach ($fruit->getElementsByTagName( "b" ) as $xmlBold) {
        echo $xmlBold->nodeValue.'<br/>';
   }
}
```